# How long does it take a hot oven to become cold

Tags: cake

The recipe calls for a cold oven and I something baking in the oven on 450. How long will it take to for it to be cold again?

Comment: The best way to find out is try it. Heat the oven up, turn it off, open the door and time how long it takes to get to room temperature. I would prefer to leave it hot for 20 minutes before turning it off so the walls and everything get hot, too. It doesn't have to get to exactly 70F but 75 or maybe even 80F is close enough.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what temperature is "cold", is it room temperature ?

it also depends how well insulated is your oven and/or if you keep the door open to let the hot air out quickly.

Comment: ... and it depends on other factors, like if the oven is built-in or standalone, how well the kitchen is ventilated etc. And if I were in one of my moods, I'd say it depends on whether the 450 is °C or °F.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Rob I disagree. If the answer is "it depends", that is also an answer. Upvoting Max's answer. In this particular case, the only possible solution would be to sneak into Minnie's kitchen and measure the time there.

Comment: @MrLister You cannot solve the problem using the contents of his "answer". There is no way to come to a conclusion. My comment is more an answer than this one cause it shows a way to come  to a conclusion but I still posted it as a comment because there is no definite answer.

Comment: @Rob Then what should the proper response be? Close the question? Or leave it open indefinitely without ever giving an answer? Or, did you mean that the OP should test this and then post the correct answer themselves?

Comment: @MrLister My comment works good but needs more detail that I don't feel like doing right now.

Comment: @MrLister The proper response is to post this "answer" as a comment seeking more details. "It depends" is not an acceptable answer in its current form. These details that it depends on should be laid out as an answer to a question (i.e. a comment), or added to the main question in response to a comment asking about the details. Downvoting.